# Splitting Polygon by Population?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, population, redistricting

I'm new to GIS. I'm working on a project right now that is about assisted living facilities in my state. I have a map of my state that I've divided into six regions by creating Thiessen polygons. The Thiessen polygons are based off of state office building locations. I also have a table of assisted living facilities that I have geocoded into a point layer. Each of these points has a population attribute that represents the population of that facility. What I would like to do is divide each Thiessen polygon into two or three regions, such that the sum of the population for the points in a region is as equal to the other regions as possible. I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Is there a tool that I can use for this?

Comment: I think "redistricting" often has a similar requirement ... have you reviewed any redistricting tools?

Comment: It appears that I don't have access to the redistricting tool.